# Alexa Skill works but says: There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

for my Alexa skill, after the "ja" intent is triggered, the skill should make a http PATCH request to my database, where it changes a number by adding 1 to it. When I test the skill in the alexa developer console and trigger the "ja" intent, alexa replies: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response", however all http requests went through and worked (the number was changed). When I remove the http request from the code, the error disappears.

This is the http PATCH Request

```
async function patch(id,data) {
  return await new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

  var options = {
    host: 'myhostname',
    path: 'my/path',
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer adsasdasdasdas",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
};


const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  let returnData = '';

  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    returnData += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', () => {
    resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
  });

  response.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
  });
});
request.write(data);
request.end();

  }));
  }


  function buildPatchData(number) {

var writeData = querystring.stringify({
  'callsthismonth': number

  });

 return writeData;
}
```

And this is the "ja" intent:

```
    'ja': async function () {

  const token = this.event.context.System.user.accessToken;
var Id = String(token);


let number = await buildPatchData(10);
let patchRequest = await patch(Id,number);




await this.emit(':tell', 'Ok, thanks for using our skill!');


    },
```

Comment: That's a pre-defined response when your skill handler throws an exception. In other words, there's something wrong with your code. Check the logs to see what's broken.

Comment: I got this message: "An error occurred while issuing a SpeechletRequest for"

Comment: Could it be that the http Request takes too long?

Comment: I got this error when my ssl web service was not configured with proper certificates. Since you are doing it on lambda check things around lambda provisions, IAM access, region of lambda endpoint (it should be Ireland for alexa to work).